# A problem about cones on a functor

Tags: category-theory

If $F:\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow\mathscr{B}$ is a functor, a cone on $F$ is by definition an object $B$ of $\mathscr{B}$ together with a family of morphisms $p_A:B\longrightarrow FA$ of $\mathscr{B}$ such that for every morphism $f:A\longrightarrow A'$ in $\mathscr{A}$, $p_{A'}\circ F(a)=p_A$.

Now consider this particular case (coming from Handbook of categorical algebra, Borceux, Vol 1 pag. 70). We have a functor $G:\mathscr{C}\longrightarrow\mathscr{D}$, which satisfies the two properties:

1) $\forall D\in\mathscr{D}\ \ \exists C\in\mathscr{C}$ and $\exists d:GC\longrightarrow D$

2) $\forall C,C'\in\mathscr{C},\ \ \ \forall D\in\mathscr{D}\ \ \ \forall d:GC\longrightarrow D\ \ \ \forall d':GC'\longrightarrow D\ \ \ \exists C''\in\mathscr{C}$

$\exists c:C''\longrightarrow C\ \ \ \exists c':C''\longrightarrow C'$ such that $d\circ Gc=d'\circ Gc'$

Now consider a second functor $F:\mathscr{D}\longrightarrow\mathscr{A}$. Every cone $(M,(q_D)_{D\in\mathscr{D}})$ on $F$ immediately induces a cone $(M,(q_{GC})_{C\in\mathscr{C}})$ on $F\circ G$. Conversely, consider a cone $(M,(r_C)_{C\in\mathscr{C}})$ on $F\circ G$. I want to prove that it induces a unique cone $(M,(q_D)_{D\in\mathscr{D}})$ on $F$ such that $q_{GC}=r_C$. To do that, I define for every object $D$ in $\mathscr{D}$, the projection $q_D:=Fd\circ r_C$. It exists since by property 1), for every $D$ I can choose an object $C$ in $\mathscr{C}$ and an arow $d:GC\longrightarrow D$ in $\mathscr{D}$, and it does not depend on this choice since by property 2), a different choice $C'$ and $d'$ produces the same composite $Fd'\circ r_{C'}=Fd\circ r_C$. Moreover, choosing $d=1_{GC}$, we get $q_{GC}=r_C$.

What I can't understand is how can be proven that $(M,(q_D)_{D\in\mathscr{D}})$ is actually a cone on $F$, that is: given a morphism $g:D\longrightarrow D'$ in $\mathscr{D}$ how can be proved that $Fg\circ q_D=q_{D'}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit dense, so let me know if I should expand certain steps.

Let there be $f:D\to D'$ in $\mathscr{D}$. Then by property 1 of $G$ there is a $d:GC\to D$ and a $d':GC'\to D'$; by property 2, there is a $C''$ and $c:C''\to C$,$c':C''\to C'$ such that $f\circ d\circ Gc=d'\circ Gc'$. It follows that $F(f\circ d\circ Gc)\circ r_{C''}=F(d'\circ Gc')\circ r_{C''}$. Because $\{r_C\}_{C\in\mathscr{C}}$ is a cone over $F\circ G$, this reduces to $Ff\circ Fd\circ r_C=Fd'\circ r_{C'}$. But this says just that $Fd\circ r_C = q_D$ and $Fd'\circ r_{C'}=q_{D'}$ satisfy the naturality condition of a cone.